Character encoding issues while uploading / downloading a CSV to Azure Blob Storage using C#
I have a service which allows users to upload and download a CSV file to update data in a system using C#. This data contains foreign characters. The file appears to upload fine. If I download and view it directly from Azure Storage Explorer all the encoding is correct. However, when I try to download using the C# service, the French and German characters get replaced with �.
You can see the files as they reside in Storage Explorer. The appear to have the correct content type.

My upload and download functions are as follows:
public async Task CreateCSV<T>(string reference, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(data);

        await SaveToBlobStorage(reference, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString()));
    }
}


public async Task<bool> SaveToBlobStorage(string filePath, byte[] data)
{
    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(Helpers.StorageConnection(), Helpers.ContainerName());

    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(filePath);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data, writable: false))
    {
        blob.Upload(stream);
        var type = MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(filePath);
        await blob.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = $"{type}; charset=utf-8" });
    }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCSV<T>(string reference)
{
    var stream = await GetStreamFromStorage(reference);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;

    IEnumerable<T> result = csv.GetRecords<T>();

    return result.ToList();
}

public async Task<MemoryStream> GetStreamFromStorage(string file)
{
    var blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(Helpers.StorageConnection(), Helpers.ContainerName(), file);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);

    return memoryStream;
}

How do I return the csv files with the correct encoding?

Did you try setting BlobHttpHeaders.ContentEncoding instead of including the encoding in the ContentType?

I did. I'm beginning to wonder if it's an Excel issue and how excel saves the data. If I explicitly save as a "CSV UTF-8" then it all works.

How is Excel related to the question?  In your question you are writing and reading back the CSV file purely using CsvHelper not Excel.

@dbc Excel is related as the client downloads a language file as a CSV, edits it in Excel then re-uploads it.

So do the French and German characters only get mangled when the client downloads and edits using Excel, or are they also getting mangled when you download via C# and edit with CsvHelper?


Character encoding issues while uploading / downloading a CSV to Azure Blob Storage using C#

I agree with dbc's comment, the above code entirely handled by csvhelper, it seems that you are already using UTF-8 encoding when you save the CSV file to Azure Blob Storage. The issue may be with how you are reading the CSV file from Azure Blob Storage.
You can see the sample code with all methods to ensure that UTF-8 encoding is maintained throughout the upload and download process.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace CsvBlobExample
{
    public class SampleData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MimeTypeHelper
    {
        public static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLowerInvariant();
            return extension switch
            {
                ".csv" => "text/csv",
                // Add other extensions as needed
                _ => "application/octet-stream", // Default for unknown types
            };
        }
    }

    public class CsvBlobService
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private readonly string _containerName;

        public CsvBlobService(string connectionString, string containerName)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _containerName = containerName;
        }

        // Method to create a CSV from a collection of data and upload it to Blob Storage
        public async Task CreateCSV<T>(string reference, IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(data);

                // Convert StringWriter content to UTF-8 bytes for upload
                byte[] encodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
                await SaveToBlobStorage(reference, encodedData);
            }
        }
        public async Task<bool> SaveToBlobStorage(string filePath, byte[] data)
        {
            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(_connectionString, _containerName);
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var blob = container.GetBlobClient(filePath);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data, writable: false))
            {
                await blob.UploadAsync(stream, overwrite: true);

                var type = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(filePath);
                await blob.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders
                {
                    ContentType = type,
                    ContentEncoding = "utf-8"
                });
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Method to download a CSV from Blob Storage and parse it back into a collection of data
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCSV<T>(string reference)
        {
            var stream = await GetStreamFromStorage(reference);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = ",",
                HeaderValidated = null,
                MissingFieldFound = null
            });

            return csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }

        // Method to get a MemoryStream of data from Blob Storage
        private async Task<MemoryStream> GetStreamFromStorage(string file)
        {
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(_connectionString, _containerName).GetBlobClient(file);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Download blob content to memory stream
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);

            return memoryStream;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat326123;AccountKey=redacted;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string containerName = "venkat";

            var csvBlobService = new CsvBlobService(connectionString, containerName);
            
            var dataToUpload = new List<SampleData>
            {
                new SampleData { Name = "François", Country = "France" },
                new SampleData { Name = "Müller", Country = "Germany" },
                new SampleData { Name = "Jürgen", Country = "Germany" }
            };

            // Reference name for the CSV file in Blob Storage
            string csvFileName = "sample_data.csv";

            // Upload the CSV file to Blob Storage
            await csvBlobService.CreateCSV(csvFileName, dataToUpload);
            Console.WriteLine("CSV file uploaded successfully!");

            var retrievedData = await csvBlobService.GetCSV<SampleData>(csvFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("CSV file retrieved successfully!");

            foreach (var item in retrievedData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name}, Country: {item.Country}");
            }
        }
    }
}

The above code helps to preserve special characters like French and German accents when writing to, saving in, and reading back from Azure Blob Storage.
Output:
CSV file uploaded successfully!
CSV file retrieved successfully!
Name: François, Country: France
Name: Müller, Country: Germany
Name: Jürgen, Country: Germany


Portal:

